# Does the word "and" omitted by speaker?

Tags: listening

The tapescript is as below:

> Well,i think we've got the basis of a really interesting presentation.Let's go and photocopy the article.

Let us hear what the speaker say:

[the and omitted or not](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f32t32k4cgd4kbw/output.mp3?dl=0)

In my ear it is:

> Well,i think we've got the basis of a really interesting presentation.Let's go photocopy the article.

The speaker omit "and" ,nothing between "go" , "photocopy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could hear the "and" word from the audio, it is the /n/ between the two words. If you find it hard to hear, try uploading the audio to online tools such as https://audiotrimmer.com/audio-speed-changer/ . Slowing down the audio to about 0.6 or even slower should help you hear the "n" sound.

Edit： Please try 0.6 - 0.7 instead.

Comment: I do as you say ,slow down till 0.5x,still can't hear the "n" between the two words.

Comment: I hear it too.  It's very much "run into" the word *go*, like "let's go'n photocopy..."

Comment: @showkey Hi! I've tried playing the audio at 0.5x and I guess it is too slow that the "n" sound got disassociated. I've tried different speeds and it seems somewhere between 0.6 - 0.7 would be the best speed for hearing the "n". Please try again with that speed, the "n" sound is more like a very quick "ern" sound, just a nasal sound.  Apologies for giving unclear directions.